# Which the efficient python library that convert pdf to images apart from Wand,ImageMagick?

Tags: python

Currently, I am using Wand library to convert the pdf to image.But the performance is too slow.Could you suggest the best library if anyone is there? Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not a field in which extensive work has been done. If you're not satisfied with what exists, you may have to be prepared to write your own library.

Comment: You could go with pdf2image. It can be used only via python3. It is a wrapper over pdftoppm.

Comment: @coldspeed I have used them while I am implementing as a lambda function.It worked well but it is taking more execution time.

Comment: @MB11 from pdf2image , I have used this   images = convert_from_path('sample.pdf'),but i am not getting where those images are stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pdf2image. It can be used only via Python 3. It is a wrapper over pdftoppm.

```
images = pdf2image.convert_from_path('pdf path', output_folder='output path')
```

Comment: It stores as a .ppm .Could I get in .jpg format?

Comment: You can use 'Pillow' module to convert ppm to jpeg.

Comment: @SrikanthMargam There is another kwarg, `fmt='jpg'`. `images = pdf2image.convert_from_path('pdf path', output_folder='output path', fmt='format')`